# How to maximize over a set containing an isolated point?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, code-request, maximum

How can I maximize a function F over a set composed by a compact set like [a, b], plus a single isolated point, like $[a, b] \cup \{p\}$?

I cannot code the isolated point part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, this can be done as follows.

```
Maximize[{x^2, 1 <= x && x <= 2 || x == Pi}, x]
```

> `{\[Pi]^2, {x -> \[Pi]}}`

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!! I didn't think about writing the isolated point directly as an "or" option...